# Laravel 5.2 SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo, access

Добрый день. Есть такой composer.json, в котором можно увидеть версии Laravel, PHP и т.д. что я использую.

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "v2.3.2",
    "doctrine/dbal": "2.3.5",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

При попытке какого-либо доступа к базе данных (при CRUD), которая находится на Хостинге получаю данную ошибку:

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user...

При этом, **Внимание**, команда миграций работает отлично и все таблицы в базе данных создаются!

```
Migrated: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как оказалось в .env есть DB_HOST с стандартным значением из примера .env.example:

> DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

но, он работает только при команде artisan migrate и при условии, что у вас локальная база данных.

Если у вас удаленный Хостинг, то, чтобы работала команда artisan migrate нужно использовать адрес хоста или его DNS.
Пример:

> DB_HOST=ru.srackoverflow.com

Если же вы хотите использовать доступ к таблицам через GRUD, то нужно прописывать:

> DB_HOST=localhost

Т.е., получается так, что от конкретного случ. нужно изменять конфигурационный файл: для миграций на локалке 127.0.0.1, для миграций на Хосте ru.srackoverflow.com, для доступа к данным localhost (миграция уже не будет работать).